# Taking a whole collection from MongoDB and use its length in Angular2

Tags: mongodb, angular

I try to take a whole collection from my MongDB database as an array and use the documents in it as array elements, and also use the array's properties(such as its length)

I am sure that I take the collection as an array correctly (i.e. I can print the documents from my console) but when I try to assign its length to a *number* variable it returns the following error:

EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at new DashboardComponent (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:300:36)
    at new Wrapper_DashboardComponent (/AppModule/DashboardComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:7:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_DashboardComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/DashboardComponent/host.ngfactory.js:15:34)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:82921:21)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:83377:52)
    at ComponentFactory.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:44314:25)
    at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:61906:62)
    at RouterOutlet.activate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:67747:40)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25277:16)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25244:26)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25180:58
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25180:29)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25154:14)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24714:22

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can print the documents from your console, then check its type.

Comment: You use db.collection.find({}, callback) mongoose function?